# Error while downloading the requirements using pip install (setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

version pip 21.2.4
python 3.6

The command:

```
pip install -r  requirements.txt
```

The content of my `requirements.txt`:

```
mongoengine==0.19.1
numpy==1.16.2
pylint
pandas==1.1.5
fawkes
```

The command is failing with this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/*/Desktop/ml/*/venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/kn/0y92g7x55qs7c42tln4gwhtm0000gp/T/pip-install-soh30mel/mongoengine_89e68f8427244f1bb3215b22f77a619c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/kn/0y92g7x55qs7c42tln4gwhtm0000gp/T/pip-install-soh30mel/mongoengine_89e68f8427244f1bb3215b22f77a619c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/kn/0y92g7x55qs7c42tln4gwhtm0000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-97994d6e
         cwd: /private/var/folders/kn/0y92g7x55qs7c42tln4gwhtm0000gp/T/pip-install-soh30mel/mongoengine_89e68f8427244f1bb3215b22f77a619c/
    Complete output (1 lines):
    error in mongoengine setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://*/pypi/packages/mongoengine-0.19.1.tar.gz#md5=68e613009f6466239158821a102ac084 (from https://*/pypi/simple/mongoengine/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mongoengine==0.19.1 (from versions: 0.15.0, 0.19.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mongoengine==0.19.1
```

Answer (score 194, accepted):

It looks like `setuptools>=58` breaks support for `use_2to3`:

[setuptools changelog for v58](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v58-0-0)

So you should update `setuptools` to `setuptools<58` or avoid using packages with `use_2to3` in the setup parameters.

I was having the same problem, `pip==19.3.1`

Comment: This solved the problem for me. anyjson>=0.3.3 failed to install, but this fixed it. Thanks

Comment: setuptools==58 actually works for me

Comment: Confirmed this was it for me as well. I installed the version before v58 using
`sudo pip3.9 install setuptools==57.5.0`
Then proceeded to install what I needed, did not receive the error.

Comment: `pip install setuptools==58` fixed it for me. I was trying to install jmespath-terminal and kept getting this error.

Answer (score 62):

I install `setuptools==58`It worked for me. `pip install setuptools==58`. The error coming from `setuptools==69` that previously run on my device. and Finally saved me setuptools version 58 for this error.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.10.6

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me.

```bash
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools==57.5.0
```

Comment: This worked for me too, but keep in mind you'll be downgrading at this point, and that may have unintended consequences down the road. 

```
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 65.6.3
    Uninstalling setuptools-65.6.3:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-65.6.3
Successfully installed setuptools-57.5.0
```

Answer (score 3):

"pip install setuptools==58" worked for me. The setuptools version was 59 when I upgraded ubuntu to 22.04 and its python 3.10. I started a clean virtual environment for an existings django project. It had just two packages:

`pip list
Package    Version

---

pip        22.0.2
setuptools 59.6.0`

Then I downgrade the setuptools to 58 as pip install setuptools==58.0.0. After that the pip install -r requirements.txt has not such error above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. Of all the answers to this, this was the most helpful. I had tried adding setuptools=58 to my requirements.txt file, but that did not fix the issue for me when installing on my docker container. Explicitly calling `pip install setuptools=58` first is what fixed this for me. So while you may not have provided the descriptive reasoning behind why this worked, your procedural explanation was more helpful than the other answers I read! It could also be made even better by adding a little description of why this works (perhaps cite the top answer, as it gives a clear descriptive answer).

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading MongoEngine to >= 0.20 would also fix the problem as Python2 support (hence `use_2to3`) was dropped in 0.20

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on Windows 11 and these solutions didn't work. I installed [pybluez2](https://pybluez.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/bluetooth_socket.html) instead. Your python version >= 3.9 on Windows.

```
pip install pybluez2
```