# Can I have some help finding out where to change a python setuptools version in this build error?

Tags: python, setuptools, plaidml

I am attempting to build a python package called plaidML from source. It uses a tool called bazelisk which says it is a wrapper for something called bazel. I am not familiar with any of these tools, just following instructions blindly.

Anyway, the build step failed, and I even kind of know why. The final error message "use_2to3 invalid" led me to pages like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100275/error-while-downloading-the-requirements-using-pip-install-setup-command-use-2). From a number of responses to various posts like this, the problem seems to be with the latest version of the setuptools package (58.2.0) and doing "setuptools==50.3.2" will resolve it.

My question is very specific. Where do I make this change? There is a huge directory tree involved here and I've been completely unable to figure out which file in all of this might be the place to add that line.

**So my question is this: Can somebody look over this build output and suggest to me where I would add a line "setuptools==50.3.2" to override setuptools 58.2.0?** Much appreciated.

This is no doubt an elementary question, but I'm finding the learning curve kind of steep and doing my best to climb it alone with the aid of Google and StackOverflow.

(Although I suppose you're never alone while there's StackOverflow. Song cue for "You'll Never Walk Alone")

**Update:** I may have a small clue. At the top level of this huge directory tree is a configure script, ./configure. It references a file called environment.yml which contains the following. Is one of those somehow forcing setuptools 58.2.0? How do I find out which?

```
cat environment.yml

channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - numpy=1.16.4
  - pip=19
  - pre_commit=1.17.0
  - python=3.7.4
  - pyyaml=5.1.2
  - pip:
    - cpplint==1.4.4
    - yapf==0.27.0
```

(Full build output)

```
$ bazelisk build //plaidml:wheel

Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Writing tracer profile to '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/command.profile.gz'
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=80
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/bazel.rc:
  'build' options: -c opt --spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone --announce_rc --nolegacy_external_runfiles --distinct_host_configuration=false --enable_platform_specific_config --action_env=LC_ALL --action_env=LANG --action_env=NO_PROXY --action_env=HTTP_PROXY --action_env=HTTPS_PROXY --action_env=no_proxy --action_env=http_proxy --action_env=https_proxy --define=version=0.0.0.dev0
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:macos in file /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/bazel.rc: --cxxopt=-std=c++17 --cpu=darwin_x86_64 --apple_platform_type=macos --build_tag_filters=-large,-linux,-msvc
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: OK

done
Installing pip dependencies: ...working... Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/condaenv.2e885f82.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Ignoring torch-nightly: markers 'platform_system == "Linux"' don't match your environment
Collecting asq
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/1b/fa14c1101a40819652718701ad6b149dd009131d7b408efb1a834a688f4f/asq-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting autodoc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/c3/61f746096d2b6c161bd7f3bf8db1fe741b8805cbf0ac9369b4953c37de35/autodoc-0.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting bokeh
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/96/3e56636664e497728b14738fea5e54297de1bc0f451b7206325a6453e73d/bokeh-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting breathe
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/3c/cf7386ab7c0b353a99265dd15081895f5efd79a4a2d02deae0d60c85d25b/breathe-4.31.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/48/58/c8aa6a8e62cc75f39fee1092c45d6b6ba684122697d7ce7d53f64f98a129/click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting defaultlist
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/e6/cf788a63ef0dcf7f352bfdd917dd51b1f59b51ff39b28b93a003e4d4ba4e/defaultlist-1.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting graphviz
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/14/b5eeeb6d24dbca0ada857ce4a453985df34d9512464bb20cc1a8aca44c54/graphviz-0.17-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting humanize
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/5e/9840102591431f86c2e99c5a8e4f18bb399f9f2e982b0dbba87c98ae800f/humanize-3.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras==2.2.4
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/10/aa32dad071ce52b5502266b5c659451cfd6ffcbf14e6c8c4f16c0ff5aaab/Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras-applications==1.0.8
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e3/19762fdfc62877ae9102edf6342d71b28fbfd9dea3d2f96a882ce099b03f/Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting livereload
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/60/6640b819e858562ef6684abac60593b7369fe0a8a064df426d3ab0ab894d/livereload-2.6.3.tar.gz
Collecting matplotlib==3.1.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1e/5cfcafca1ebe7b5fc08dcc2fe5efc7307e6970de0dd2999a7757311a7aec/matplotlib-3.1.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting networkx
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/93/aa6613aa70d6eb4868e667068b5a11feca9645498fd31b954b6c4bb82fa5/networkx-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/4d/9df2841432757b45d5b9973d85c982d4984aa2baea7ff48a905baa5fc781/pandas-1.3.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting pcpp==1.20.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/7b/e8ca3707a86a21685214cbe8d7d77a71a2964dfef01c1fe9bbfad9ff6b39/pcpp-1.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: pygments in /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/condaenv.2e885f82.requirements.txt (line 16)) (2.10.0)
Collecting pystache
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/fd/eb8c212053addd941cc90baac307c00ac246ac3fce7166b86434c6eae963/pystache-0.5.4.tar.gz

failed
Pip subprocess error:
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    pystache: using: version '58.2.0' of <module 'setuptools' from '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'>
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
    error in pystache setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.


CondaEnvException: Pip failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/conda_wrapper.py", line 225, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/conda_wrapper.py", line 218, in main
    subprocess.check_call(['conda'] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['conda', 'env', 'create', '-f', '/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/unix.yml', '-p', '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix' which is a conda_repo (rule definition at /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/conda_repo.bzl:32:14):
 - /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/workspace.bzl:155:5
 - /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/WORKSPACE:22:1
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix':
   conda_repo failed: Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: OK

done
Installing pip dependencies: ...working... Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/condaenv.2e885f82.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Ignoring torch-nightly: markers 'platform_system == "Linux"' don't match your environment
Collecting asq
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/1b/fa14c1101a40819652718701ad6b149dd009131d7b408efb1a834a688f4f/asq-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting autodoc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/c3/61f746096d2b6c161bd7f3bf8db1fe741b8805cbf0ac9369b4953c37de35/autodoc-0.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting bokeh
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/96/3e56636664e497728b14738fea5e54297de1bc0f451b7206325a6453e73d/bokeh-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting breathe
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/3c/cf7386ab7c0b353a99265dd15081895f5efd79a4a2d02deae0d60c85d25b/breathe-4.31.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/48/58/c8aa6a8e62cc75f39fee1092c45d6b6ba684122697d7ce7d53f64f98a129/click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting defaultlist
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/e6/cf788a63ef0dcf7f352bfdd917dd51b1f59b51ff39b28b93a003e4d4ba4e/defaultlist-1.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting graphviz
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/14/b5eeeb6d24dbca0ada857ce4a453985df34d9512464bb20cc1a8aca44c54/graphviz-0.17-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting humanize
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/5e/9840102591431f86c2e99c5a8e4f18bb399f9f2e982b0dbba87c98ae800f/humanize-3.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras==2.2.4
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/10/aa32dad071ce52b5502266b5c659451cfd6ffcbf14e6c8c4f16c0ff5aaab/Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras-applications==1.0.8
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e3/19762fdfc62877ae9102edf6342d71b28fbfd9dea3d2f96a882ce099b03f/Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting livereload
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/60/6640b819e858562ef6684abac60593b7369fe0a8a064df426d3ab0ab894d/livereload-2.6.3.tar.gz
Collecting matplotlib==3.1.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1e/5cfcafca1ebe7b5fc08dcc2fe5efc7307e6970de0dd2999a7757311a7aec/matplotlib-3.1.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting networkx
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/93/aa6613aa70d6eb4868e667068b5a11feca9645498fd31b954b6c4bb82fa5/networkx-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/4d/9df2841432757b45d5b9973d85c982d4984aa2baea7ff48a905baa5fc781/pandas-1.3.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting pcpp==1.20.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/7b/e8ca3707a86a21685214cbe8d7d77a71a2964dfef01c1fe9bbfad9ff6b39/pcpp-1.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: pygments in /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/condaenv.2e885f82.requirements.txt (line 16)) (2.10.0)
Collecting pystache
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/fd/eb8c212053addd941cc90baac307c00ac246ac3fce7166b86434c6eae963/pystache-0.5.4.tar.gz

failed
 (Pip subprocess error:
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    pystache: using: version '58.2.0' of <module 'setuptools' from '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'>
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
    error in pystache setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.


CondaEnvException: Pip failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/conda_wrapper.py", line 225, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/conda_wrapper.py", line 218, in main
    subprocess.check_call(['conda'] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['conda', 'env', 'create', '-f', '/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/unix.yml', '-p', '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
)
ERROR: /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/plaidml/BUILD:322:1: //plaidml:wheel depends on @com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix//:python in repository @com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix which failed to fetch. no such package '@com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix//': conda_repo failed: Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: OK

done
Installing pip dependencies: ...working... Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/condaenv.2e885f82.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Ignoring torch-nightly: markers 'platform_system == "Linux"' don't match your environment
Collecting asq
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/1b/fa14c1101a40819652718701ad6b149dd009131d7b408efb1a834a688f4f/asq-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting autodoc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/c3/61f746096d2b6c161bd7f3bf8db1fe741b8805cbf0ac9369b4953c37de35/autodoc-0.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting bokeh
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/96/3e56636664e497728b14738fea5e54297de1bc0f451b7206325a6453e73d/bokeh-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting breathe
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/3c/cf7386ab7c0b353a99265dd15081895f5efd79a4a2d02deae0d60c85d25b/breathe-4.31.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/48/58/c8aa6a8e62cc75f39fee1092c45d6b6ba684122697d7ce7d53f64f98a129/click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting defaultlist
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/e6/cf788a63ef0dcf7f352bfdd917dd51b1f59b51ff39b28b93a003e4d4ba4e/defaultlist-1.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting graphviz
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/14/b5eeeb6d24dbca0ada857ce4a453985df34d9512464bb20cc1a8aca44c54/graphviz-0.17-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting humanize
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/5e/9840102591431f86c2e99c5a8e4f18bb399f9f2e982b0dbba87c98ae800f/humanize-3.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras==2.2.4
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/10/aa32dad071ce52b5502266b5c659451cfd6ffcbf14e6c8c4f16c0ff5aaab/Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras-applications==1.0.8
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e3/19762fdfc62877ae9102edf6342d71b28fbfd9dea3d2f96a882ce099b03f/Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting livereload
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/60/6640b819e858562ef6684abac60593b7369fe0a8a064df426d3ab0ab894d/livereload-2.6.3.tar.gz
Collecting matplotlib==3.1.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1e/5cfcafca1ebe7b5fc08dcc2fe5efc7307e6970de0dd2999a7757311a7aec/matplotlib-3.1.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting networkx
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/93/aa6613aa70d6eb4868e667068b5a11feca9645498fd31b954b6c4bb82fa5/networkx-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/4d/9df2841432757b45d5b9973d85c982d4984aa2baea7ff48a905baa5fc781/pandas-1.3.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting pcpp==1.20.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/7b/e8ca3707a86a21685214cbe8d7d77a71a2964dfef01c1fe9bbfad9ff6b39/pcpp-1.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: pygments in /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/condaenv.2e885f82.requirements.txt (line 16)) (2.10.0)
Collecting pystache
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/fd/eb8c212053addd941cc90baac307c00ac246ac3fce7166b86434c6eae963/pystache-0.5.4.tar.gz

failed
 (Pip subprocess error:
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    pystache: using: version '58.2.0' of <module 'setuptools' from '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'>
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
    error in pystache setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.


CondaEnvException: Pip failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/conda_wrapper.py", line 225, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/conda_wrapper.py", line 218, in main
    subprocess.check_call(['conda'] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['conda', 'env', 'create', '-f', '/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/unix.yml', '-p', '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
)
ERROR: Analysis of target '//plaidml:wheel' failed; build aborted: no such package '@com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix//': conda_repo failed: Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: OK

done
Installing pip dependencies: ...working... Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/condaenv.2e885f82.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Ignoring torch-nightly: markers 'platform_system == "Linux"' don't match your environment
Collecting asq
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/1b/fa14c1101a40819652718701ad6b149dd009131d7b408efb1a834a688f4f/asq-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting autodoc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/c3/61f746096d2b6c161bd7f3bf8db1fe741b8805cbf0ac9369b4953c37de35/autodoc-0.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting bokeh
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/96/3e56636664e497728b14738fea5e54297de1bc0f451b7206325a6453e73d/bokeh-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting breathe
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/3c/cf7386ab7c0b353a99265dd15081895f5efd79a4a2d02deae0d60c85d25b/breathe-4.31.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/48/58/c8aa6a8e62cc75f39fee1092c45d6b6ba684122697d7ce7d53f64f98a129/click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting defaultlist
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/e6/cf788a63ef0dcf7f352bfdd917dd51b1f59b51ff39b28b93a003e4d4ba4e/defaultlist-1.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting graphviz
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/14/b5eeeb6d24dbca0ada857ce4a453985df34d9512464bb20cc1a8aca44c54/graphviz-0.17-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting humanize
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/5e/9840102591431f86c2e99c5a8e4f18bb399f9f2e982b0dbba87c98ae800f/humanize-3.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras==2.2.4
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/10/aa32dad071ce52b5502266b5c659451cfd6ffcbf14e6c8c4f16c0ff5aaab/Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras-applications==1.0.8
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e3/19762fdfc62877ae9102edf6342d71b28fbfd9dea3d2f96a882ce099b03f/Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting livereload
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/60/6640b819e858562ef6684abac60593b7369fe0a8a064df426d3ab0ab894d/livereload-2.6.3.tar.gz
Collecting matplotlib==3.1.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1e/5cfcafca1ebe7b5fc08dcc2fe5efc7307e6970de0dd2999a7757311a7aec/matplotlib-3.1.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting networkx
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/93/aa6613aa70d6eb4868e667068b5a11feca9645498fd31b954b6c4bb82fa5/networkx-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/4d/9df2841432757b45d5b9973d85c982d4984aa2baea7ff48a905baa5fc781/pandas-1.3.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting pcpp==1.20.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/7b/e8ca3707a86a21685214cbe8d7d77a71a2964dfef01c1fe9bbfad9ff6b39/pcpp-1.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: pygments in /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/condaenv.2e885f82.requirements.txt (line 16)) (2.10.0)
Collecting pystache
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/fd/eb8c212053addd941cc90baac307c00ac246ac3fce7166b86434c6eae963/pystache-0.5.4.tar.gz

failed
 (Pip subprocess error:
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/dz/p7vwr87j4yg47b6nrkry4ww00000gn/T/pip-install-3x9e1iqq/pystache/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    pystache: using: version '58.2.0' of <module 'setuptools' from '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'>
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
    error in pystache setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.


CondaEnvException: Pip failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/conda_wrapper.py", line 225, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/bzl/conda_wrapper.py", line 218, in main
    subprocess.check_call(['conda'] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['conda', 'env', 'create', '-f', '/Users/rpoepa/opt/anaconda3/envs/dl-tf2/src/plaidml-master/conda/unix.yml', '-p', '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_rpoepa/fad1b61d3201ac45b9bbed1789e4f56f/external/com_intel_plaidml_conda_unix/env']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
)
INFO: Elapsed time: 340.511s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (8 packages loaded, 9 targets conf\
igured)
```

Comment: What is confusing me is all of these temporary subdirectories under /private/var/tmp and other places. So I'm thinking that setuptools 58.2.0 is being created somewhere in that temporary structure. I just had the thought that maybe it's already part of my python installation, so I did "conda list setuptools" and got version 58.0.4, confirming that 58.2.0 is somewhere else.

Comment: This is the [`environment.yml`](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/blob/0.7.0/environment.yml), you probably have to pin `setuptools` to 57.5 there. Not familiar wirh conda though.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the pystache version in setup.py file

```
install_requires=[
        'pystache == 0.5.0'
    ]
```