# cannot install anyjson even have downgraded setuptools==57.5.0

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-2to3, anyjson

I cannot install anyjson even have downgraded setuptools==57.5.0,
Here is what I have run.

```
 % pip install setuptools==57.5.0
 % pip install anyjson==0.3.3
Collecting anyjson==0.3.3
  Using cached anyjson-0.3.3.tar.gz (8.3 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in anyjson setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Comment: The `anyjson` version 0.3.3 entry on PyPI is from June 2012. It claims to support Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and 3.1. You may need to downgrade your Python version. And probably your OS along the way.

Comment: In other words: it's far outdated. I recommend that you don't use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76366622/7976758 `pip install "setuptools<58.0.0" wheel anyjson` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=anyjson+error+in+setup+command%3A+use_2to3+is+invalid

Comment: ok I just avoid is better. the pip install setuptools with 57.5.0 didnt help either. Thanks again.