Can't install pybluez
I am gatting this error while installing pybluez using command: pip install pybluez.Please someone give me solution for this.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pybluez
  Using cached PyBluez-0.23.tar.gz (97 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

(Win 11 , Python 3.12.3)
I also tried pip install --upgrade setuptools to upgrade setuptools and still getting error.

Search for this error, which came from the subprocess: "PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid"

Probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72414481/error-in-anyjson-setup-command-use-2to3-is-invalid
